# Utopian Tree in F#

Tags: programming-challenge, functional-programming, f#

This is the Utopian Tree in F# (from HackerRank)

> The Utopian tree goes through 2 cycles of growth every year. The first
>   growth cycle of the tree occurs during the monsoon, when it doubles in
>   height. The second growth cycle of the tree occurs during the summer,
>   when its height increases by 1 meter. Now, a new Utopian tree sapling
>   is planted at the onset of the monsoon. Its height is 1 meter. Can you
>   find the height of the tree after N growth cycles?

This helped me understand what to do:

```
//N = 0 ret initial height
//N = 1 ret double height
//N = 2 ret double height, +1 
//N = 4 ret double, +1, double, + 1
```

Anywhere that I could improve this F# code? I'm trying to stay within the parameters of functional language programming. Per the doc on HackerRank, I had to take in n parameters, 0 being the number of test cases followed by the number of growth cycles:

```
[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 

    let tests = System.Int32.Parse(System.Console.ReadLine())
    let cycles = [for i in 1..tests -> System.Int32.Parse(System.Console.ReadLine())]

    let even h = h * 2
    let odd h = h + 1
    let rec height acc cycle n =
        match cycle - cycle + n with
            | c when c = cycle -> acc
            | c when c % 2 = 0 -> height (even acc) cycle (n+1)
            | _ -> height (odd acc) cycle (n+1)

    cycles |> List.map (fun c -> height 1 c 0) |> List.map (fun x -> System.Console.WriteLine x)

    0 // return an integer exit code
```

Example input/ouput:

```
3
0
1
4
1
2
7
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A few points:

1. The value `i` on the second line is not used. It is customary to use underscore to name such values.
2. The expression `cycle - cycle + n` seems a bit redundant :-)
3. If you swap the last two arguments of `height`, you can use it in partially applied form as argument to `List.map` on the last line (i.e. `List.map (height 1 0)`), instead of introducing extra lambda.
4. The parameter `cycle` is improperly named: it doesn't signify a "cycle", but rather the "total number of cycles".
5. In the "real world" (e.g. if you were designing a library or something), you shouldn't expose your "temporary state" parameters (i.e. `acc` and `n`) to the consumer. Instead, you should expose just the function with one parameter ("total number of cycles"), and have the actual recursive function private.
6. Functions `even` and `odd` seem weirdly named: they don't do what they say. Either name them correctly (like, `evenYearGrowth`) or get rid of them altogether (personally I prefer the latter).
7. The very last lambda (the one calling `WriteLine`) is also redundant: it just passes its argument directly to another function, so it can be replaced with that function.
8. The last `List.map` call has a result of non-unit type (namely, `List<unit>`), which causes the compiler to produce a warning on that line (along the lines of "the result is being discarded, blah-blah-blah"). If you want to call a function on every element of the list solely for its side effects, use `List.iter`.
9. Depending on performance considerations and expected problem size, the use of `List` may be a problem: mapping over a list (i.e. `List.map`) allocates a new list, which you don't actually need, because you're just reading values and "passing them through a pipeline", so to say. You don't need to remember them. In these circumstances, I use `seq`.
   On the other hand, the use of `Seq` all through will result in outputting each result right after receiving each input, which may or may not be the desired behavior. I don't know if it is, so I will leave the input acquisition as is.
10. The `System.Int32.Parse(System.Console.ReadLine())` piece looks kinda scary and unclean. Plus, it's repeated twice. So I would make it a separate function.
11. Lastly (though this one is a matter of taste), I would use a string of `if`s instead of the `match`. Seems shorter and cleaner.

So, having said all of the above, here is my version:

```
let main argv = 

    let height =
      let rec h acc n totalCycles =
        if n = totalCycles then acc
        elif n % 2 = 0 then h (acc * 2) (n+1) totalCycles 
        else h (acc + 1) (n+1) totalCycles 
      h 1 0

    let readInt = System.Console.ReadLine >> System.Int32.Parse
    let tests = readInt()
    let cycles = [for _ in 1..tests -> readInt()]

    cycles
      |> Seq.map height 
      |> Seq.iter System.Console.WriteLine

    0 // return an integer exit code
```

Comment: Oh god #2... I'm a moron! LOL

Comment: I've only recently started but this is much cleaner... thank you for the detailed run-down! There's a lot of things I can learn from this rewrite.

Comment: Glad to help :-)